# How to use value from dynamic array

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I have dynamicly allocated array (via malloc) of numbers (called "double** metrix") and I need to get the right values and send them to the other function.

I can print the value rightly by using `printf("%d", metrix[1][1])` but when I try something like `double number; number = metrix[1][1]` I get random number (probably randomly selected part of memory?).

How to use this right to get the value I need? Thank you for any help and sorry for my english.

Comment: `double** metrix` and `printf("%d", metrix[1][1])`...I smell trouble...

Comment: why not posting the full code you wrote, so we'll get a better perspective of what you're talking about?

Comment: my code has over 1200 lines - I have just one question => how to correctly assign value from dynamic array?

Comment: Ideally you want to make a short example representing the issue you have, that way we can help you much more easily.

Comment: A minimal example that shows the unwanted behaviour is needed here...

Comment: You need to show us how you allocate and assign `metrix`, as well the context of both the `printf` and assignment statements.

Comment: added part of code where I allocate metrix (without filling it)

Comment: As a start: %d stands for decimal integer, not double. What you want is %f

Comment: the code you show for double x = matrix[i][j] is correct. Your problem is elsewhere thats why we need to see the real code. Make a small failing example - you will find the bug yourself probably

Comment: I added it already. Steffen is right, that whas the whole problem :). So thank you for your help! Can I choose it somehow as "solved"?

Comment: @JaxCze almost too easy ;) but I made it an answer if that is what solved the issue, then that it is... Nevertheless you should read about 2D arrays in C/C++ as there are a lot of pitfalls.

Comment: this `double** metrix` says that metrix is an array of pointers to pointers, so there needs to be a call to malloc for each entry in `metrix`.  Then each of those 'new' allocated memory areas need to be set to a double value (in a 32bit architecture you can expect each of those latter calls to malloc() to request 8 bytes.   However, then the printf() calls would not work.  Please post a short example that shows the problem, so we know what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%d` stands for *decimal integer*, not double. What you want is `%f` which means *(fixed) floating point*

Answer (score 1):

If you use malloc function, it only allocates a block of size bytes of memory, but the content of the newly allocated block of memory is not initialized, remaining with indeterminate values.

And if you want to print a double value, please use "%f" instead "%d"